# NHibernate QueryOver with sub-query and alias

Tags: c#, nhibernate, hql, subquery, queryover

I'm struggling to convert the following (simplified) HQL to QueryOver:

```
select subscription
from Subscription as subscription
where not exists (
    from Shipment as shipment
    where shipment.Subscription = subscription
    and (shipment.DeliveryDate  = :deliveryDate)
)
```

I've come this far:

```
Subscription subscription = null;

Session.QueryOver(() => subscription)
    .Where(Subqueries.NotExists(QueryOver.Of<Shipment>()
        .Where(shipment => shipment.Subscription == subscription)
        .And(shipment=> shipment.DeliveryDate == deliveryDate)
        .Select(shipment => shipment.Id).DetachedCriteria));
    .TransformUsing(new DistinctRootEntityResultTransformer());
```

The problem is that the above `Subqueries` and `Where` statement gives me the following (invalid) where clause:

```
where shipment.SubscriptionId is null
```

when what I want is:

```
where shipment.SubscriptionId = subscription.Id
```

So the alias and its row-level value isn't taken into account when constructing the SQL, instead its initial value `null` is used to compare to the `Shipment`'s `SubscriptionId`.

### Update

With dotjoe's provided solution, I was able to write the `QueryOver` statement as follows:

```
Subscription subscription = null;

Session.QueryOver(() => subscription)
    .WithSubquery.WhereNotExists(QueryOver.Of<Shipment>()
        .Where(shipment => shipment.Subscription.Id == subscription.Id)
        .And(shipment => shipment.DeliveryDate == deliveryDate)
        .Select(shipment => shipment.Id));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
.Where(shipment => shipment.Subscription.Id == subscription.Id)
```

Comment: I'd guess you can't use the alias variable for implicit Id comparison. I think you could only do it that way if you were using an actual (loaded) Subscription object.

Comment: I see. A bit un-intuitive given how ID comparison is usually done in NHibernate, but as long as it works, I'm happy. Thanks! :)  I've updated my question regarding the missing `distinct` keyword in the resulting SQL, do you have any idea why it is missing?

Comment: The `distinctrootentitytransformer` is not the same as the SQL `select distinct` . That transformer is there for when you join a collection into the query and want to make sure you don't get duplicate root entities back. It does all the work on the client side.

Comment: So if I want a `distinct` in the resulting SQL, what should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do a `select distinct` in NH. Since you'd have a primary key in the Subscription table, that would make `distinct` pointless. You can get the equivalent of distinct by doing a projection with group by...`SelectList` + `SelectGroup`

Comment: It's possible to do `select distinct` with HQL, so you'd think it should be possible with `ICriteria` and `QueryOver` as well. Either way, you're correct: my `distinct` isn't needed (as I have no joins). Thanks!